# laravel 4 preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to store values of 2 different tables in an array and then to display values in view. I have 2  tables "cars" and "classes". Table cars has a field named "class" which contain the id of class table and table class has fields "class" and "id". I am making the follow queries:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $data['values'] = DB::select('select * from cars where id = ?', array($id));
    $class = DB::select('select class from cars where id = ?', array($id));  
    $data['class']= DB::select('select class from classes where id = ?', array($class)); 
    $data['classes'] = DB::table('classes')->orderBy('class', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('class', 'id');
    return View::make('pages.edit', $data);
}
```

and in view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('class', 'Class', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        {{ Form::select('class', $classes ,$class->class,array('class' => 'form-control') ) }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

in $class i want to save the id of class for that specific car. Is there any other way to do this without inner join ?? it displays the following error:

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// this returns array(stdClass('class'=>'classValue'))
$data['class']= DB::select('select class from classes where id = ?', array($class)); 

// so simply do this:
$classArray= DB::select('select class from classes where id = ?', array($class)); 
$data['class']= $classArray[0];
```

Comment: {{ Form::select('class', $classes, $class, array('class' => 'form-control') ) }}

Comment: line 3 - there's undefined `$class` variable, it's not the view. And in the Form::select use $class->class as it's still object property

Comment: sorry it was another error. Now it shows this Undefined variable: class (View: C:\wamp\www\national\app\views\pages\edit.blade.php)

Comment: and now here $classArray = DB::select('select class from classes where id = ?', array($class)); "undefined variable: class"

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/VqEMn   and  :preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: Arual, `$class` in the controller is an object, so in the view you need to use `$class->class` like I said

Comment: {{ Form::select('class', $classes, $class->class, array('class' => 'form-control')) }} and: "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array"  and now?

Comment: Read the comments in that paste and fix what needs to be fixed

Comment: but when i try to put array($class) as string ($class)it shows errors. I am really confused right now.

Comment: This will do http://laravel.io/bin/3jRw2, hope the rest is good and will not throw more errors..

Comment: now it works for some rows but for others shows : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Comment: Again: paste the error with stack trace, otherwise its guessing

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[175]
      public 'class' => string 'Mini' (length=4) var_dump shows this

Comment: I told to pass the object to the view and there you call $class->class ($class is that object, ->class is its property) not array.

Comment: I know that you told me but when $class->class it shows : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: just solved it. It needed a foreach. I was so tired so I couldn't think clearly. Thank you for your help :)